# Formula works in Excel but not Google Spreadsheet - IFERROR using a VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

The below information I was able to get to work find in Excel but cannot get it to work in Google Spreadsheets.

This is the **formula that works in Excel :**

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,{1,25;2,50;3,75},2),0)*IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2,0)="T",2,1)
```

I am trying to get a cell to calculate points for me based on a few criteria.

**Points:**

- Qty of 1 = 25 points
- Qty of 2 = 50 points
- Qty of 3 = 75 points.

Team members do not receive points for more than a quantity of 3. The quantities still get recorded but no additional points.

If team member has a `T` in the next column then they get double the points

If team member has a `O` in the next column then they get standard points.

**On Sheet 1, the "Team Member" is picked from a drop list in Sheet 2 from the "Team Member" names**

Sheet1:

```
        A            B        C
1   Team Member   Quantity  Points
2   Josh           1
3   Jo             2
```

Sheet2:

```
        A            B
1   Team Member   Code
2   Josh           T
3   Nate           T
4   Jo             O
5   Daniel         O
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in Sheet1 `Jo` should be in A3 instead, right?

And in B2, there should be 1, 2 or 3 (or something else that yields 0 points).

If that is so, you can use `CHOOSE` instead of `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(B2,25,50,75),0)*IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2,0)="T",2,1)
```

Apparently, `VLOOKUP` in GoogleSpreadsheet cannot take an array in that form, but only a range, meaning that if you make a table somewhere with the point distributions, it will work.

---

EDIT: Since there can be quantities above 3, I'd suggest this modification:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MIN(B2,3),25,50,75),0)*IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2,0)="T",2,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jerry.  You are right about Jo and the column.  When I plugged your formula in it seem to work until I picked a few other choices.  Here is my spreadsheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkYvn9U2nf47dGk1UzBIMVBuWGxOdWYwOUV4OE16d0E&usp=sharing

Comment: @user3237612 Okay, I see what was the problem. It's because you are having quantities above 3, which means you would have to make some threshold check, for when it's above 3. I changed your spreadsheet's formula so that it's now `MIN(B2,3)` instead of only `B2` there.

Comment: Awesome.  I truly appreciate you taking the time.  I have been stuck on this for over day now.  You just made my weekend just a little better.

Comment: @user3237612 Glad that I could make someone's weekend better, even if it's by a little =P

Comment: One thing I just found is that if you pick a "Team Player" and the next field "Quantity" is blank it defaults to 75 points. If you add a quantity then it figures it correctly.  Any ideas on what to add to not show points until a quantity is put in?